# Positive Sequence (ABC) Balanced Delta Load Vector Diagram

Tags: transformer

Why isn't Vab at 0 degrees angle?

Source:

PPI PE Power Reference Manual, 4th Edition – Comprehensive Reference Manual for the Closed-Book NCEES PE Exam

Publisher : PPI, A Kaplan Company; Fourth edition (January 31, 2021)

ISBN-10 : 1591267838

ISBN-13 : 978-1591267836

by John A. Camara PE

[image]

Comment: Who says it's not? Where's the reference point that you see?

Comment: @jonk Because Vab is at -120 degrees. It's very obvious!

Comment: Cool. And exactly where's the \$0^\circ\$ reference, then?

Comment: What matters is the relationship between phasors.  You can use any arbitrary reference, all that does is rotate the entire phasor diagram.

Comment: @jonk the 0 degrees reference is Vca. I don't understand what are you trying to say!

Comment: @OMAR relayman explains what I was trying to suggest.

Comment: OMAR, @jonk was trying to get you to think. There is no 0° reference point shown on the diagram and no X/Y axes.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of reference angle is arbitrary.  I like to put A-phase voltage on the right axis (labeled 0° in my figure below), but it is just my preference.  I have seen author's who like to put A-phase voltage on the vertical axis and make it the 0° mark. To jonk's point, the author could assign the 0° mark to \$V_{AB}\$.

What matters in phasor diagrams is the relationship **between** the phasors.  Choosing the arbitrary reference angle merely rotates the entire diagram.

Assuming the voltages are balanced, we know that the A-phase-ground voltage will be within ±30° of the A-B voltage.  That, coupled with the information that this is an A-B-C rotation (the order in which the phasors pass a fixed point on the diagram when rotated counterclockwise) system allow us to located the 3 phase-ground voltage phasors (\$V_A\$,\$V_B\$, and \$V_C\$) as I show below.  From this, you can see that the A-phase current, \$I_A\$, lags the A-phase voltage by 30°.

[image]

Note: The \$V_{AB}\$ phasor is \$V_A - V_B\$ which you find by simply negating the \$V_B\$ phasor and adding it "head-to-tail" with the \$V_A\$ phasor.  The resultant being \$V_{AB}\$ which we know is \$\sqrt{3}\$ longer than the phase-ground phasors.